2013 Cadillac CTS Coupe. Where is the rear parking assist control module located?
CTS Coupe 2013 . Where is the rear parking assist module located? I’m getting a service park assist message on the DIC.

More than likely, one of the sensors is having a problem or is no longer recognized by the system or has come out of calibration. I'd doubt the module itself is having the issue. The sensors are in the bumper, but I wouldn't know how to check any individual one to make sure it is good.
